# Concealing a radar detector

Tags: electrical

I've seen some guides online for hard-wiring a radar detector into the electrical system of the car via the moon-roof line or similar.  But what about concealing the detector itself.

I'd like to disassemble the detector, carefully de-solder the components, lengthen connectors and expose the minimal sensor components in the windshield, and hide the bulk of the unit in the roof or something.

Anyone done this?  Thoughts?

Comment: @uosef - I'm sorry, but I don't believe this is the place to ask questions about illegal modifications.

Comment: The modification isn't illegal.

Comment: @uosef - You yourself have said that "radar detectors are not allowed where [you] live".  That lends to the likelihood that you are in one of many jurisdictions where radar detectors are outlawed.  Therefore, this modification would be illegal.

Comment: Well, the modification would be legal in some places, so the question could be of general interest. I think the issue of doing the wiring is on-topic, but the issue of how best to conceal the hardware is off-topic.

Comment: don't know about manually disassembling a unit, but there are companies that sell detectors which are designed to integrate with the car, just as you described. You might want to be careful though because detector receivers actually generate RF signals which can be picked up externally. So if they are illegal where you live and they detect you have one anyway, your whole car might end up impounded.

Comment: As an aside, I wonder how that works with those few cars that have factory installed, non-removeable radar detectors?  Whole car get impounded or is there an exception allowed as that's the factory configuration (similar to the tire wider than wheelwell issue, illegal many places, but a handful of older cars were like that from the factory).

Comment: Another down vote for this guy?  What, do you folks fancy yourself to be the police?

Comment: In a word: Valentine1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no electronics engineer, but a radar detector is a radio receiver.  It will have tuned circuits, and it is entirely possible that changing the length of a connecter to an antennae may affect the operation of the circuit.  It is also entirely possible that it will have no effect.

That would/could be one of the main issues.

Also, for laser detection, sensor placement is very important - but you do say you already intend to place the sensors in the windshield.